# Помогите. Как кастомизировать ползунок при клике на кнопку JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. 
У меня имеется ползунок:

```js
var range = document.querySelector('.news__lenta-radio-volume-input');
$('.news__lenta-radio-plus').click(function () {
    //
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news__lenta-radio-minus">-</div>
<input class="news__lenta-radio-volume-input" id="step" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
<div class="news__lenta-radio-plus">+</div>
```

И я хочу чтобы при клике на "+" положение увеличивалось на 5 шагов, а при клике на "-" уменьшалось на 5 соответсвенно. Как я могу реализовать это? Заранее благодарен в любом содействии касаемо моего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var range = document.querySelector('.news__lenta-radio-volume-input');
var plus = document.querySelector('.news__lenta-radio-plus');
var minus = document.querySelector('.news__lenta-radio-minus');

plus.addEventListener('click', function(){
  range.value = +range.value + 5;
});

minus.addEventListener('click', function(){
  range.value = +range.value - 5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news__lenta-radio-minus">-</div>
<input class="news__lenta-radio-volume-input" id="step" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
<div class="news__lenta-radio-plus">+</div>
```